# How reliable is current_kernel_time()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, benchmarking, linux-device-driver

I am working on performance benchmarking of a SDIO UART Linux/Android driver and used current_kernel_time() at start and end of the to-be-analysed read, write function implementation, then printing the time difference.

Most of the time I get time difference as 0 (zero) nanoseconds (irrespective of size of the data to read/write : 16-2048 bytes) which logically I think is incorrect, only a very few times I get some values hopefully those are correct.

How reliable is the current_kernel_time()?

Why I get 0ns most of the times?

I am planning to profile at kernel level to get more details..before that can somebody throw some light on this behavior..has anybody observed anything like this before...

Also, any suggestions to help/correct my approach to benchmarking are also welcome!

Thank you.

EDIT:
This is the read code from Linux kernel version 2.6.32.9. I added current_kernel_time() as below under #ifdef-endif:

```
static void sdio_uart_receive_chars(struct sdio_uart_port *port, unsigned int *status)
{
#ifdef SDIO_UART_DEBUG
struct timespec time_spec1, time_spec2;
time_spec1 = current_kernel_time();
#endif

    struct tty_struct *tty = port->tty;
    unsigned int ch, flag;
    int max_count = 256;

    do {
        ch = sdio_in(port, UART_RX);
        flag = TTY_NORMAL;
        port->icount.rx++;

        if (unlikely(*status & (UART_LSR_BI | UART_LSR_PE |
                        UART_LSR_FE | UART_LSR_OE))) {
            /*
             * For statistics only
             */
            if (*status & UART_LSR_BI) {
                *status &= ~(UART_LSR_FE | UART_LSR_PE);
                port->icount.brk++;
            } else if (*status & UART_LSR_PE)
                port->icount.parity++;
            else if (*status & UART_LSR_FE)
                port->icount.frame++;
            if (*status & UART_LSR_OE)
                port->icount.overrun++;

            /*
             * Mask off conditions which should be ignored.
             */
            *status &= port->read_status_mask;
            if (*status & UART_LSR_BI) {
                flag = TTY_BREAK;
            } else if (*status & UART_LSR_PE)
                flag = TTY_PARITY;
            else if (*status & UART_LSR_FE)
                flag = TTY_FRAME;
        }

        if ((*status & port->ignore_status_mask & ~UART_LSR_OE) == 0)
            tty_insert_flip_char(tty, ch, flag);

        /*
         * Overrun is special.  Since it's reported immediately,
         * it doesn't affect the current character.
         */
        if (*status & ~port->ignore_status_mask & UART_LSR_OE)
            tty_insert_flip_char(tty, 0, TTY_OVERRUN);

        *status = sdio_in(port, UART_LSR);
    } while ((*status & UART_LSR_DR) && (max_count-- > 0));
    tty_flip_buffer_push(tty);

#ifdef SDIO_UART_DEBUG
time_spec2 = current_kernel_time();
printk(KERN_INFO "\n MY_DBG : read took: %ld nanoseconds",
    (time_spec2.tv_sec  - time_spec1.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + (time_spec2.tv_nsec - time_spec1.tv_nsec));
#endif

}
```

Comment: Why don't you show some code? It's hard to tell what's wrong with something you can't see.

Comment: What platform?  This type of question is pretty hardware-specific (or at least architecture-specific)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added the code.  I am trying this on Linux (32 bit Dell Laptop) as well as Android (Android Dev Phone).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

current_kernel_time is meant for timekeeping, not for performance measurement.
It returns, a value, not based on an actual timer, but on a time value that is updated by a timer interrupt. So the precision depends on the timer interrupt period.
and you get poor resolution.

However, perhaps `getnstimeofday`, is more suited to your need, since it also read the actual clock source to adjust the time value. It should be more fine grained.

Based on kernel [source](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L400), maybe the best function is `getrawmonotonic`, in the unlikely event that the system time is adjusted backward during your measurement.

Comment: Thanks, shodanex! getnstimeofday() gives consistent time values in ns, as logically expected the numbers increase relatively with increase in data size.